# remote rejected master -> master (TFS: The Write permission is required to perform this action for the supplied reference.)

Tags: git, github, tfs

I'm cloning into an empty repository. Once that is done I'm doing the following:

1) git add .

2) git commit -m "first commit"
(everything is okay so far)

3) git push
(here I'm getting an error)

I thought I don't have write permissions so checked the TFS but I do have it. Everything in TFS' Access Control summary says "Inherited Allow".

Then I thought maybe I cant push into master so created a new branch but still getting the same error [remote rejected] test-> test

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For almost all permissions, **deny** trumps **allow**, so if a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to **deny**, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to **allow**.

So please make sure the groups which you belong to all have the write permission. You can use `TfsSecurity.exe /server:xx:8080/tfs /im n:tfstrain \username` this command to list all group of the user.